# Uploading APN cert in GCM error

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, apn

I want to update my expired cert in GCM but their uploader seems to be not working. My certificate is not updating. Here is the image of error in GCM

[image]

What is seem to be the problem here? I tried other browser or device but still not working. Is google know about this?

Comment: Having same problem. @Jibo you found the solution?

Comment: @kctang nope, sorry. We decided to go with firebase instead.